# How to do Binding Stackpanel and stringFormat?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have some stackpanel that have under him 4 textblock that need to show some information. 
I do some binding of the stackpanel ( DataContext ) and binding the textblock with the information that will hold by the object that was bind to the stackpanel.

I wrote the code + xaml and nothing work. 
I get exception about format wrong.

The code:

```
 public partial class SomeDemoClass: UserControl
{
    classObjDemo c1;

    public SomeDemoClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        c1 = new classObjDemo()
        {
              val1 = 5.5,
              val2 = 2.3
        }; 
    }
 }
```

The xaml ( that match the class 'SomeDemoClass' )

```
   <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SomeDemoClass, Path=c1">

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding val1, StringFormat={0:F} }" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding val2, StringFormat={0:F} }" />


   </StackPanael>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of you put x:Name="SomeDemoClass" in the  in the op of your xaml and make c1 a public property instead of a field it would work. ElementName references elements in your xaml by name and binding only works on properties and dependency properties.

```
<UserControl x:Name="SomeDemoClass" ...

public classObjDemo c1 { get; set; }
```

Also check your Visual Studio output window for binding errors.

EDIT

Also make sure v1 and v2 of the classObjDemo are public properties

And escape { in your xaml. See http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding val2, StringFormat={}{0:F} }" />
```

Comment: its impossible to understand what you wrote.

Comment: I add this to my code - change the field to be a property - and nothing happand. still does not work.

Comment: And also make sure val1 and val2 of classObjDemo are properties, not fields

Comment: yes, thay are properties. and the error that i get is " Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'. "

Comment: i also check the option of    Text="{Binding val1, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}     and still not working

Comment: Ah, yes, escaping the {}. I've changed my answer again